# Can't import passlib into python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, passlib

Trying to import passlib into python3 and it fails:

```
$ pip freeze | grep lib
passlib==1.6.5

$ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 10:45:20)

>>> import passlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'passlib'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pip` will install a library for python 2. If you want to install it for python 3 too, you must do so separately:

```
$ python3 -m pip install passlib
```